# How to get items that are true for ANY() method in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say:

```
x = 'A/B'
any(signs in x for signs in ['/' , '+', '-'])
```

How to get the signs it found true in the iteration?
Here's a way

```
for sign in ['/' , '+', '-']:
    if sign in x:
        print(sign)
```

Is there a better one liner way of doing it?
(Without the for loop maybe)

Comment: `[c for c in x if c in {'/', '+', '-'}]`

Comment: or: `list(filter(lambda i: i in ['/' , '+', '-'], x)) # out: ['/']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the few modifications to the `any` expression, you can get whether each of the signs is in the expression, which signs are in the expression, or just the first such sign:

```
>>> any(sign in x for sign in ['/' , '+', '-'])
True
>>> [sign in x for sign in ['/' , '+', '-']]
[True, False, False]
>>> [sign for sign in ['/' , '+', '-'] if sign in x]
['/']
>>> next((sign for sign in ['/' , '+', '-'] if sign in x), None)
'/'
```

(In the last one, `None` is the default in case no such element exists.)

Comment: Thanks! last one is the answer I was seeking for. That helps.

Answer (score 1):

My solution

```
from re import findall
findall(r'[/+-]', x)
```

But please note there are some subtle differences in the various suggestions:

- `any` will stop (and of course return True, not what it found) as soon as it finds *one* sign. So if your input string is very long and has a sign in the first few position it will be quicker than anything else.
- your loop will return *once* each sign which appears in the input string, and not necessarily in the order they appear
- The list comprehension, `filter()`, and `findall()` will return *all* the signs in the input string, as many times as they appear and in the order they are found

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom function, if the logic is complex, or [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) with a [lambda function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lambda) if the logic is simple, like in your case.

```
def func(string, signs):
    for c in string:
        if c in signs:
            yield c

selected = list(func("A/B", ["/", "+", "-"]))
print(selected) #['/']


selected = list(filter(lambda i: i in ["/", "+", "-"], "A/B"))
print(selected) #['/']
```